# How can I texture a large terrain mesh in OpenGL?

Tags: textures, terrain, terrain-rendering, mesh

I want to apply a texture to a large terrain mesh in my game. I think that it is just not acceptable to have a gigantic UV map spanning over 4096 x 4096 pixels.

What's a better way to apply a texture to it?

Comment: it is acceptable to have a such a large UV map,

Comment: There are plenty of ways. e.g. there's even megatexture approach (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MegaTexture).

Comment: Have a look at "texture splatting", that might work for you. I'll be rescinding my answer as I cannot be specific enough about solving your use case to warrant one.

Comment: You may also try a `detail texture` approach where you use one smaller texture as you main color (rock/grass/road/etc.) and another one with some kind of a noise and much tiling, to add more detail.